# Gmaps4Rails v2 - removeMarkers() not working after calling addMarkers()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I have a function responsible for hiding/showing markers, so I decided to use removeMarkers() and addMarkers() with a variable which contains all markers displayed on map, preventing AJAX requests. However, removeMarkers() appears to not working when used after addMarkers() function:

```
#/assets/javascript/general.js.coffee
@buildMap = (markers)->
  provider = Gmaps.build(
    'Google',
    {
      builders: { Marker: RichMarkerBuilder},
      markers:
        clusterer:
          gridSize: 50
          styles: [
            url: "/assets/cluster.png"
            textSize: 15
            width: 56
            height: 56
          ]
    }
  )
  Gmaps.handler = @clustereredHandler()
  Gmaps.handler.buildMap {
    provider: provider,
    internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
      Gmaps.markers = _.map(markers, (marker_json) ->
        marker = Gmaps.handler.addMarker(marker_json)
        _.extend marker, marker_json
        marker
      )
      Gmaps.map = Gmaps.handler.getMap()

      Gmaps.handler.bounds.extendWith(Gmaps.markers)
      Gmaps.handler.fitMapToBounds()

#app/views/stores/index.html.erb
buildMap(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
```

So, I have:

- Handler on `Gmaps.handler` variable;
- All markers on `Gmaps.markers` variable;
- Map on `Gmaps.map` variable.

Steps to failure:

1. Load map - OK (All markers loaded correctly);
2. > `Gmaps.handler.removeMarkers(Gmaps.markers)` - OK (All markers hidden correctly);
3. > `Gmaps.handler.addMarkers(Gmaps.markers)` - OK (All markers shown correctly);
4. > `Gmaps.handler.removeMarkers(Gmaps.markers)` - FAILURE! (Markers still being displayed);

I'm using `2.1.2`version. Is there any fix for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [my plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2iO0x7X9o77vNSFknE5F?p=preview), there is no bug with gmaps4rails.

I feel like you have an issue with your own functions (maybe dont use extend?) and replace with:

```
marker.json  = marker_json
```

I cant tell much more since they are not included.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in saving the markers. Whenever you add new markers, you overwrite the old ones. Try

```
Gmaps.markers.push.apply(Gmaps.markers, Gmaps.handler.addMarkers(Gmaps.markers))
```

to append the new markers instead.